# Delay for executing the function not working - JS

Tags: javascript, html

I read this article: [wait 5 seconds before executing next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226803/wait-5-seconds-before-executing-next-line) and It didn't work for me.
Now I have this code in my project:

```
const sleep = async (milliseconds) => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        return setTimeout(resolve,milliseconds)
    })
}
```

and then I want to use this:

```
await sleep(1500);
console.log("waited for 1.5 seconds.")
```

Visual Studio Code says "'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules."
and I don't get it.

I tried the other solutions in the link I attached but none of them worked for me. Probably I'm missing something but I don't know what it is.

Comment: In other words, I don't see "waited for 1.5 seconds." in console log.

Comment: Put that code inside an async function.

Comment: `(async function() { await sleep(1500); console.log("waited for 1.5. second";})()`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks but it's not working yet. Are the parentheses and curly brackets correct?

Comment: No, should be `(async function() { await sleep(1500); console.log("waited for 1.5. second");})()`

Comment: @Barmar I get this error in the cosole "Uncaught TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function"

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe you've done something to override your `console.log`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607224/console-log-is-not-a-function-in-nodejs-6-9-1

Comment: @Barmar Oh I got it.  I had not filled the milliseconds part with digits.